# Дан массив. Удалить из массива все элементы, встречающиеся более 2-х раз

Tags: php

Дан массив. Удалить из массива все элементы, встречающиеся более 2-х раз.Удаляю 
элементы,но вместо них(удаленных элементов) появляются нули,как от них избавиться?

```
  $arr=[5,0,5,9,-3,4,0,5,6,7,8,-9,0];
   $count = 0; 
    $n=count($arr);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
    { 
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) 
        { 
            if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j])
            {
                $count++; 
                $a=$j;
            }
        }      
        if($count >= 2) 
        { 
            for ($j = $a; $j < $n-1; $j++) 
            { 
                $arr[$j] = $arr[$j+1]; 
            } 
            $n--;
            for ($j = $i; $j < count($arr)-1; $j++) 
            { 
                $arr[$j] = $arr[$j+1]; 
            }
            $arr--;  
        } 
        $count = 0; 
    } 

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        echo $arr[$i]." "; 
}
```

Comment: в образце ни один элемент три и больше раза не встречается, вроде

Comment: @splash58,вы ошибаетесь

Comment: не ошибаюсь, поправь заголовок на `не менее`

Comment: @splash58,не менее 2-х раз и более 2-х раз, одно и тоже

Comment: `более 2 раз` - 2 не входит :)

Comment: @splash58,входит,лучшеб с кодом помогли бы

Comment: не входит, а с кодом давно помог, тока ты не смотришь :)

Comment: более 2 раз это >2 не менее 2 раз это >= 2

Comment: @splash58,это ясно исходя из условия, понятно что при программировании вы будете использовать  >= 2 в цикле, придераетесь на пустом

Comment: как-то глаз режет, когда на родном языке неправильно пишут, надо бы поприд**И**раться :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы как-то так это делал. Только ключи будут не последовательными.

```
$arr=[-1,0,5,9,-3,4,5,6,7,8,-9,0];
$count = 0; 
$n=count($arr);
$a = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) 
  for ( $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) 
    if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]) $a[$i][] = $j;

foreach($a as $item)
  if(count($item) >= 2) 
     foreach($item as $key)
       if (isset($arr[$key])) unset($arr[$key]);
echo implode(' ', $arr)."\n";
```

Comment: ,спасибо за помощь

Comment: да не за что :)

Comment: php, выдает кучу Notice: Undefined offset:

Comment: вот это наверное надо переставить до циклов `$a = array();`. У меня нет возможности запустить пхп

Comment: eva.in не пишет предупреждений. или я не умею. отпиши, что получилось

Comment: всё также  Notice: Undefined offset  :(

Comment: Убрал единственное опасное место, где удаление элементов происходит

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: через 10 минут я буду за нормальным компом, посмотрю, отпишусь

Comment: вот мутная строка    <code>     $a[$i][] = $j;     </code>,   хотя наверное ошибаюсь

Comment: Нет, это отличная строка. я просто в твоем обилии скобок запутался :)) Все работает нынче. А "мутная строка" - очень правильный оператор. Добавляет элемент в массив

Answer (score 2):

Зачем изобретать велосипед?
Есть же уже готовое решение
[Вот](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: про эту функцию я знаю,мне  нужно свой велосипед поправить прост ;)

Comment: Не создавайте ответов-ссылок. Лучше вынести какую-то информацию в сам ответ и добавить ссылку в конце. Иначе, если сайт будет недоступен, ссылка вместе с ответом перестанут быть актуальными